# Weblogic: No EJBs found in the ejb-jar file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, ejb, weblogic

When I try to deploy the Java EE project to **weblogic 12c**, I get the following error

`No EJBs found in the ejb-jar file`

However, this only happens when I deploy the EAR source folder and let weblogic compile it (split development directory). If I build the EAR first with ant and deploy it, it deploys fine.

I think the problem has something to do with the fact, that EJB module has *both* annotations and `ejb-jar.xml` descriptor present. Everything else is handled with annotations, and `ejb-jar.xml` just introduces the `ejb-client-jar` as such.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:ejb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>EJB</display-name>
  <ejb-client-jar>EJBClient.jar</ejb-client-jar>
</ejb-jar>
```

Also, `weblogic-ejb-jar.xml` is used for additional configuration.

But what makes pre-built EAR and source deployment behave differently in this case and how to solve the problem? Application is using Java EE 5 and EJB 3.0.

Comment: Comment from @Boris_Ndong https://stackoverflow.com/users/8265954/boris-ndong :  How did you solve this problem ? I'm facing the same issue right now.

Comment: sorry, can't remember

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue.  I solved it by adding creating the "ejb-jar.xml" file and put that under project->src->resources->META-INF .

### Here was the content  :

```
<ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">

    <enterprise-beans>
        <session>
            <ejb-name>className </ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>packageName.className</ejb-class>
            <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
        </session>
    </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```